# Entity Framework Map With Fake Foreign Key Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

My models:

```
class FooEntity
{
    [Key]
    int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Bar"), Column("other_id")]
    int OtherId { get; set; } // <-- This should be the FK

    virtual BarEntity Bar { get; set; }
}

class BarEntity
{
    [Key]
    int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("other_id")]
    int OtherId { get; set; } // <-- This is the other side of the FK
}
```

Essentially I want to reproduce this SQL:

```
select *
from foo f
left join bar b on b.other_id = f.other_id -- AND other conditions to "guarantee" uniqueness
```

But with the model building configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FooEntity>()
.HasOptional(f => f.Bar)
.WithRequired()
.Map(m => m.MapKey("other_id"))
.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I end up with the error: "Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'other_id' is already defined." But when I add:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BarEntity>().Ignore(b => b.OtherId);
```

before the other configuration, I get the error: "the specified type member 'OtherId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

So how can I get this working? Changing the underlying data structure is absolutely not an option.

Answer (score 1):

- In EF6 an FK must point back to a PK.
- In your RDBMS it could depend on the implementation. Sql Server will allow an FK back to a non PK column as long as there is a unique index constraint. Other RDBMS might or might not allow it.

I recommend you omit the FK relationship and when you need to retrieve both entities manually include the join in your Linq/Lambda statement.

Comment: To clarify, a FK in EF6 must point back to a PK.  In SQL Server and EFCore, a FK can reference any candidate (i.e. unique) key.

Comment: Not quite.  In EF6 an Entity can have only one Key (perhaps compound).  The Entity's Key columns should be a PK or Unique Index in the RDBMS, but if you have multiple keys in the database, you can pick any one for your Entity Key.  But all FKs in EF must point to that one Key.

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut for what you want to accomplish; you will need to create the query manually, something along the lines of:

```
dbContext.Foos
    .GroupJoin( 
        dbContext.Bars, 
        f => f.OtherId, 
        b => b.OtherId,
        ( foo, bars ) => new { foo, bars } )
```